# Command WPF C# CheckEdit

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброе время суток!
Возникла проблема с CheckEdit, никак незнаю как связать данные

XAML

```
<dxe:CheckEdit Content="DEBUG"   Padding="2.5" Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

C#

```
  public List<DataText> list;

    public TextViewModel()
    {

        list = new List<DataText>();
        DataT = new List<DataText>();
    }


      #region Command

    private RelayCommand _openCommand;

    public ICommand OpenCommand
    {
        get { return _openCommand = new RelayCommand(param => OpenDial(), param => CanOpen); }
    }

    private void OpenDial()
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fb = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        DialogResult result = fb.ShowDialog();

        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(fb.SelectedPath); // папка с файлами
        var files = new List<string>(); // список для имен файлов

        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.txt")) // извлекаем все файлы и кидаем их в список
        {
            // files.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName));// получаем полный путь к файлу и потом вычищаем ненужное, оставляем только имя файла.
            files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.FullName));
        }
        list = ReadTextFile.LoadDateListFromFile(files);

        DataT = list;

    }
    public bool CanOpen
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    #endregion

    public List<DataText> DataT
    {
        get { return list; }
        set
        {
            list = value;
            OnPropertyChange("DataT");
        }
    }
```

нужно чтобы показать или скрить данные при нажатие на checkedit, К примеру если нажать на debug то все данные типу debug пропадають

вот работа данной программы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых во вью модели надо задать свойства для ваших чекбоксов. Например так

```
bool _isDebugVisible;

public bool IsDebugVisible
{
    get
    {
        return _isDebugVisible;
    }
    set
    {
        _isDebugVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChange(nameof(IsDebugVisible));
        OnPropertyChange(nameof(DataT));
    }
}
```

в xaml ваш чекбокс будет выглядеть примерно так

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDebugVisivle}"/>
```

при условии, что датаконтекстом у него является ваша вьюмодель. Иначе нужно указать явно, откуда брать свойство `IsDebugVisible`

И так для всех чекбоксов. А для `DataT` геттер будет выглядеть как то так

```
public List<DataText> DataT
{
    get 
    { 
        return list.Where(dt => ну и тут условия по всем вашим чекбоксам).ToList();
    }
    set
    {
        list = value;
        OnPropertyChange("DataT");
    }
}
```

И да. Если вы получаете результирующую коллекцию не целиком, а по частям, то, как сказал Николай, List лучше заменить на ObservableCollection

Comment: А почему название `IsDebugVisible`?

Comment: @VladD, потому что свойство отвечает за видимость строк по параметру Debug.

Comment: Хм, и правда. Согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, забудьте про List. Отвратительная вещь, особенно когда речь о Binding'ах. Замените

```
public List<DataText> list;
```

на

`public ObservableCollection<DataText> list;`
 (кстати, названия публичный свойств принято писать с большой буквы)

Ну и DataT поменять так-же соответсвенно.
Далее, следует просто описать логику изменения коллекции в связи с вашими нуждами.